# Issue converting special characters from SQL to XML using XML PATH

Tags: sql-server, xml

Encountering an issue while attempting to convert some special characters into proper XML. Instead, it's returning XML which is failing for the calling application.

This is part of a much larger chunk of code. I must use XML PATH, otherwise it will require refactoring the entire procedure, which is outside the scope of this work.

I have attempted to replace the values, and tried replacing the values both before and after. I'm unable to perform an extra pass on the subsequent returned XML

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #MyData
    GO

    CREATE TABLE #MyData
    (
       RefId varchar(20) NOT NULL,
       Company varchar(255) NOT NULL
    );
    GO

    INSERT INTO #MyData (RefId, Company) VALUES ('SN7172', 'Goodle '+CHAR(0174));
    INSERT INTO #MyData (RefId, Company) VALUES ('GW5282', 'NewtownApple '+CHAR(0169));
    INSERT INTO #MyData (RefId, Company) VALUES ('ZE0018', 'Curlewky Appliances '+CHAR(0151));
    INSERT INTO #MyData (RefId, Company) VALUES ('TW1037', 'Sparky Games '+CHAR(0153));
    GO

    SELECT (
        SELECT RefId, 
            REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Company, char(0174),'&#0174'),     char(0169),'&#0169'), char(0153),'&#0153'), char(0151),'&#0151') Company
        FROM #MyData
        FOR XML PATH('Catalog'), TYPE
    )
    FOR XML PATH('Catalogs'), TYPE
```

The SQL is being converted to `&amp;#0174;` instead of `&#0174;`
Yet, the XML below shows the ampersand being converted, rather than the full string.

```
    <Catalog>
        <RefId>GW5282</RefId>
        <Company>Newtown &amp; Apple &amp;#0169;</Company>
    </Catalog>
    <Catalog>
        <RefId>ZE0018</RefId>
        <Company>Curlewky Appliances &amp;#0151;</Company>
    </Catalog>
    <Catalog>
        <RefId>TW1037</RefId>
        <Company>Sparky Games &amp;#0153;</Company>
    </Catalog>
    </Catalogs>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do I get this correctly? The XML your SQL-Server produces is correct (something like `<Company>NewtownApple ©</Company>`), but your consumer cannot deal with the `©` and therefore you want to use the entity instead. Correct?

One hack might be to convert the resulting XML and do the replacements there on string base:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST(
(
    SELECT (
        SELECT RefId, Company
        FROM #MyData
        FOR XML PATH('Catalog'), TYPE
    )
    FOR XML PATH('Catalogs'), TYPE) AS nvarchar(MAX)), char(0174),'&#0174;'),     char(0169),'&#0169;'), char(0153),'&#0153;'), char(0151),'&#0151;');
```

But do not try to cast the result back to XML. You would get the special characters back...

Comment: Thanks. It’s converting them back, as the column is XML. Ugh

Comment: @AllanL, The XML within SQL-Server is correct, the problem is on your consumer's side I'm afraid... The only way to go seems to be the string route. Important to know: XML is not stored as as the string you see but as a hierarchy table. The XML you see is re-created whenever you ask for it. And there is little to no chance to tell SQL-Server how to deal with special characters. You might read about `<!DOCTYPE>` and self defined entities (e.g. `<!DOCTYPE myEntities [<!ENTITY copyright "&#0169;">]>`. You can use `&copyright;` in your XML. But this will get automatically translated too.